# deploying same war with different name in jboss 5

Tags: jboss5.x

I have a scenario where i need to deploy the same war with different names (like TestA, TestB, etc.) for different clients. Each war file connect to different databases. So i am copying the same war with different names, with respective database connection properties.

**Connection Properties for TestA**

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TESTADB
hibernate.connection.username = testa
hibernate.connection.password = testa
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

**Connection Properties for TestB**

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TESTBDB
hibernate.connection.username = testb
hibernate.connection.password = testb
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

But only TestA is running, other wars are not running.

I have deployed all the wars in `F:/jboss-5.0.0./server/default` folder of JBOSS.

I browse the application using

```
http://localhost:8080/TestA
http://localhost:8080/TestB
```

Answer (score 0):

In each war, try to configure the jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web> 
<context-root>/TestA</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

and

```
<jboss-web> 
<context-root>/TestB</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

This should work....